# Computer shuts down after installing Nvidia drivers

Tags: 14.04, drivers

I just recently installed the graphic card driver for a GeForce GT 435M. But when I use Ubuntu the computer shuts down suddenly.

First I setup the xorg-edgers ppa with

```
sudo add-apt repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa -y
sudo apt-get install nvidia- current
```

I then checked the installation with

```
lspci -vnn |grepp -i VGA -A 12
```

and the kernel was set as nvidia. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I think the driver is overheating the graphic card.

I want to know if there's any solution.

Comment: How you installed nvidia graphics driver?

Comment: Using sudo apt-get install nvidia-current

Comment: full command with details - if one cannot understand your problem they can't provide you any answer also.

Comment: First I setup the xorg-edgers ppa with   

$ sudo add-apt repository  ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa -y   
                      
 $ sudo apt-get install nvidia- current    

 I then checked the installation with    

 $ lspci -vnn |grepp -i VGA -A 12    

 and the kernel was set as nvidia            I'm running ubuntu 14.04 LTS.       
I think the driver is overheating the graphic card...

Comment: Sorry for the text format, I'm writing from my cellphone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `nvidia-common` is depreciated, follow these steps to install the driver correctly

Remove the one you have

```
sudo add-apt repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

Now install this one

```
sudo add-apt repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Its working fine, thank you. Just in case I installed the 304 version

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well on a Ubuntu server 20.04, after installing the NVIDIA drivers with `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`. Somehow it changed my standby mode status.

You can see the status of your standby services using:

```
systemctl status sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

To mask/disable the standby services run:

```
systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

After you can check that the services are masked again with:

```
systemctl status sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

This prevents to system to standby automatically.